# How to amalgamate (screen.width < X) with $(window).scroll(function()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script which pops in an overlay `div` at the bottom of the page when you scroll down a few pixels and then removes it when you reach the bottom of the page.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
if ($(this).scrollTop() < 10){
    $("#giveaway").css({"position": "fixed", "bottom": "-100px"});
}
if ($(this).scrollTop() > 11){
    $("#giveaway").css({"position": "fixed", "bottom": "0"});
}
if ($(this).scrollTop() > 2000){
    $("#giveaway").css({"position": "fixed", "bottom": "-100px"});
}
});
```

So when you scroll down past `11px`, the script shows that `#giveaway` div for a while and then removes it further down the page at around `2000px`.

The problem is, this covers an important element on smaller resolutions. For smaller resolutions, I'd like the div to appear a little further down. So, for screen widths smaller than, say, `750px`, I'd like, for example:

```
if ($(this).scrollTop() < 500){
    $("#giveaway").css({"position": "fixed", "bottom": "-100px"});
}
if ($(this).scrollTop() > 501){
    $("#giveaway").css({"position": "fixed", "bottom": "0"});
}
if ($(this).scrollTop() > 2000){
    $("#giveaway").css({"position": "fixed", "bottom": "-100px"});
}
});
```

So, in other words, for the `#giveaway` div to come in a bit lower down on the page. I have looked at and experimented with `if (screen.width < xxx) {`, as I believe it's a function that's in the ballpark of what I'm looking for, but being new to `JS`, I'm not exactly sure how to fit it into the above script. Is there a way to have `if screen.width` work in tandem with the above script, so that when the screen resolution is larger, the script fires as normal but when we have a screen size of `if (screen.width < 900)`, the div appears lower down?

Comment: ;) You use `< 10`, `> 11` and `< 500`, `> 501`... What should happen in the dark zone of `10, 11, 500, 501`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any N px checks.  If all you need is:

> *Hide the giveaway popup while ElementY or ElementZ are visible*

all you need is the [intersectionObserver API<sup>*MDN*</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API)
and a CSS class like `.show` that will bring into view your `#giveaway` Element.

This way you don't have to care about Mobile or Desktop, or placing magic numbers like the hard-coded 2000, 500 etc... - which may vary anyways and bug your application.

```js
const EL_give = document.querySelector('#giveaway');
const EL_head = document.querySelector('#header');
const EL_foot = document.querySelector('#footer');

function giveawayHandle(entries) {
  const isIn = entries.some(entry => entry.isIntersecting);
  EL_give.classList.toggle('show', !isIn);
}

const giveaway_observer = new IntersectionObserver(giveawayHandle);
giveaway_observer.observe(EL_head);
giveaway_observer.observe(EL_foot);
```

```css
/*QuickReset*/* {margin: 0;box-sizing: border-box;}
body {font: 14px/1.4 sans-serif; border: 4px dashed #000;}

#header { background: #b0f; padding: 20px; }
#main   { background: #eee; padding: 20px; height: 200vh; }
#footer { background: #f0b; padding: 20px; height: 30vh; position: relative; }

#giveaway {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: #0bf;
  padding: 40px 20px;
  transition: transform 0.4s;
  transform: translateY(100%); /* DEFAULT HIDDEN */
}

#giveaway.show {
  transform: translateY(0%);   /* SHOW IF JS SAYS SO */
}
```

```html
<div id="header">HEADER (Hide giveaway while I'm visible)</div>
<div id="main">Scroll Down...</div>
<div id="giveaway">GIVEAWAY!</div>
<div id="footer">IMPORTANT FOOTER (Hide giveaway while I'm visible)</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Roko. This looks interesting and I think will suit my use case. Give me a little while to implement this and I'll check back with you soon.

Comment: This works great. And I was even able to add an up/down toggle to it too with const EL_give2 = document.querySelector('#toggle');. Thanks, Roko.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a variable that sets the trigger position

```js
var heightToShowPanel = screen.width < 900 ? 500 : 10
```

And then use that in your conditionals instead of fixed numbers

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
if ($(this).scrollTop() < heightToShowPanel){
    $("#giveaway").css({"position": "fixed", "bottom": "-100px"});
}
if ($(this).scrollTop() > heightToShowPanel + 1){
    $("#giveaway").css({"position": "fixed", "bottom": "0"});
}
if ($(this).scrollTop() > 2000){
    $("#giveaway").css({"position": "fixed", "bottom": "-100px"});
}
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, menor. This seems a good solution but I went with Roko's intersectionObserver in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$(window).width()` with `scrollTop()` like this, but don't forget, use `else` and don't repeat `if` everytime.

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  let WindowWidth = $(window).width();
  let scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
  let el = $("#giveaway");

  if (WindowWidth > 750) { // screen bigger than 750px
    if (scrollTop < 10) {
      console.log('less than 10px') // less than 10px
      el.css({
        "position": "fixed",
        "bottom": "-100px"
      });
    } else if (scrollTop > 2000) {
      console.log('bigger than 2000px') // bigger than 2000px
      el.css({
        "position": "fixed",
        "bottom": "-100px"
      });
    } else {
      console.log('bigger than 10px') // bigger than 10px
      el.css({
        "position": "fixed",
        "bottom": "0"
      });
    }
  } else {
    // screen less than 750px
    if (scrollTop < 500) {
      console.log('less than 500px') // less than 500px
      el.css({
        "position": "fixed",
        "bottom": "-100px"
      });
    } else if (scrollTop > 2000) {
      console.log('bigger than 2000px') // bigger than 2000px
      el.css({
        "position": "fixed",
        "bottom": "-100px"
      });
    } else {
      console.log('bigger than 500px') // bigger than 500px
      el.css({
        "position": "fixed",
        "bottom": "0"
      });
    }
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 3000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="giveaway-wrapper">
  <div id="giveaway-background">
    <div id="giveaway" class="content">
      <h3>...lorem ipsum...</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

*Try this example in current size and also click on full page!*

Comment: Thanks for your time, Pedram. A good solution too but I went with Roko's intersectionObserver in this case.